# Turn computer into a proxy server

Tags: proxy

basically I am trying to make my computer a proxy server, so I can access my internet from school through google chrome 'Proxy Switchy!'.

I was looking on google but I cant find anything useful, do you guys know of anything?

Comment: More details please. Can you access your computer from school? If not then what all can you? If yes, then what is the problem with accessing other sites as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck! The ever-fantastic [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5469038/bypass-heavy+handed-web-filters-with-your-own-proxy-server?skyline=true&s=i) just ran a story on exactly how to do this!

Because link-only answers will eventually rot, the above is a guide on how to install [PHProxy](https://github.com/PHProxy/phproxy), which is a proxy server that you can install on your own machine or webserver.

Comment: Just set it up on my website. Anyone can do it. (seeing as I am 12)

Comment: Nah this isn't really what I was looking for, it will get blocked quickly by my school, I was looking for a proxy ip and port to enter directly into chrome

Comment: hm? This "turns your computer into a proxy server", are you looking for somebody else's proxy to use? IMO, this is the best option - if they use DNS filtering, you can get past it by using your IP, and if they block by IP, you can turn your router off for 10 minutes, most likely getting a new IP! If you're looking for a port/ip sort of thing, take a look at SSH tunneling, which is also encrypted, so they can't see what you're looking at. Do it over port 443 (The port HTTPS uses) and they can't block it without breaking a good portion of the web, and can't tell it apart from alright traffic.

Comment: Hey, my school block the proxy's somehow, but I used a private proxy, where when I typed it in to the proxy on chrome, it popped up with a user login, I logged in and I could access every page.

I want to create a personal proxy like '81.105.234.137:8085' but with my own port etc....

Comment: It sounds like you definately want to look into SSH tunnelling then. It'll use your home connection, and won't let any admins see what you're looking at.

Comment: This is what's wrong with link-only answers - the links eventually rot.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I still see that link as being alive (thankfully!), so I've summarised it in place.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look into getting an ssh server set up, and [tunneling everything through that](http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html)- this will make it practically impossible for anyone to snoop on what you're doing, You'd need putty and an ssh server (most linux distros come with one, or i suppose you can use freessh or something like that).

Another advantage is the basic tactic will work with *anything* as long as you have it set up right

Comment: I followed all of the steps, and it says that my network is unreachable? I am using a switch, could this be the problem?

Comment: have you forwarded port 22 to the server?