# Turn my windows notebook into proxy server

Tags: windows, proxy, squid

I need to install and configure squid on my notebook with windows, so that if i enter my 3g modem, i will be able to access my proxy from all over the world....
Not i have installed squid, but don't know how to configure it to access from other machines (can access only localhost:3128)...

Now i have something like:

```
http_port 192.168.1.3:3128
visible_hostname myproxy

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl LAN src 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
acl HTTP port 80 443
acl Vasya src 192.168.1.10

http_access deny Vasya
http_access allow LAN HTTP
```

Please help me to configure it....   Connect proxy server on my machine from other machines...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn computer into a proxy server](https://superuser.com/questions/108193/turn-computer-into-a-proxy-server)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [CCProxy](http://youngzsoft.net) or [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com) for this purpose.

Comment: hm.... it seems that proxifier is just proxy client, but i must do proxy on my machne

Comment: Try CCProxy then

Comment: how to configure ccproxy to access from web, but not from localhost?

Comment: You have to put your proxy server address on the computer you want to use the internet from as the IP address of the PC which has CCProxy installed on it. I think this works only on LAN.

Comment: This will help you probably? http://superuser.com/questions/270999/route-all-the-traffic-through-my-laptop-using-squid-wit-windows?rq=1

Comment: didn't helped..... only on local is working(

Comment: maybe something like vpn.... but will i be able to connect to pc from other net?